# How to add an Image to an ScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiscrollview

I develop an App in Xcoode and I add an ScrollView. Now I added some little Images in a Row.

```
let myImages = ["BallBeispielBlau.png","BallBeispielRot.png","BallBeispielGelb.png","BallBeispielBlau.png","BallBeispielRot.png","BallBeispielGelb.png","BallBeispielBlau.png","BallBeispielRot.png","BallBeispielGelb.png"]
    let imageWidth:CGFloat = 66
    let imageHeight:CGFloat = 66
    var xPosition:CGFloat = 0
    var scrollViewSize:CGFloat=0

    for image in myImages {
        let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: image)!
        let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.image = myImage

        let LongTapGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "InfosZuEinemEvent:")
        LongTapGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(LongTapGestureRecognizer)
        myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
        myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
        myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition
        myImageView.frame.origin.y = 0

        ScrollViewFreunde.addSubview(myImageView)
        ScrollViewFreunde.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        xPosition += imageWidth
        scrollViewSize += imageWidth
    }
    ScrollViewFreunde.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewSize, height: imageHeight)
```

That works fine but I want it that the six image so the image which come after the five image where show under the first image so in the second row. I try it with an if statement but it doesn´t work. I hope you could help me.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Add the code for the if statement you tried so we can tell you how to fix it. Otherwise, you should look into using a `UICollectionView`. It's built to do this.

Comment: see this once , it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056219/multiple-image-in-scrollview/24056398#24056398

Answer (score 2):

You should reeeeally use a Collection View for this. It is really easy and way better to display items in a matricial form.

However, to answer your question...

You can create a "yPosition" variable that will be incremented by imageHeight every time one image overflows the scrollView visible frame.

When this happens, xPositions goes to 0.

```
var yPosition = 0

for image in myImages {
    let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: image)!
    let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    myImageView.image = myImage

    let LongTapGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "InfosZuEinemEvent:")
    LongTapGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
    myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(LongTapGestureRecognizer)
    myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
    myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
    myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition
    myImageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition

    ScrollViewFreunde.addSubview(myImageView)
    ScrollViewFreunde.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    xPosition += imageWidth

    if xPosition + imageWidth >= view.frame.width {
        xPosition = 0
        yPosition += imageHeight
    }
    scrollViewSize += imageWidth
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer `collectionview` instead of `scrollview`. Its just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a stack view for this reason, you can download a sample project at:

https://github.com/mcmatan/StackViewWithAutoLayout

Its pretty straight forward, you just call "addSubviewWithLayout" and add your view.
The stack view will manage the scroll content size.
You can call "removeViewWithLayout" to remove a view from the stack.

Cheers